# How to make a certain setting blink to show user which setting need to be changed - Android widget

Tags: android-fragments, widget, android-preferences

I work on Android widget with the ConfigActivity.
I have there SettingsFragment which extends PreferenceFragmentCompat.
In the Settings, I have a setting which leads a user to the to android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS

Is there any way to make one of the setting "blink" to show the user which setting needs to be changed?

I attached two photos of the "blinking" setting in Chrome when the system prompts a user to enable/disable one of the settings. I could not capture the first bit of the "blinking" effect but it starts from a small white dot, similar to when someone tap on the screen when in developer "Show taps" option is enabled.

I've tried to search for: "blink", "flash" the settings for Android but I found nothing.
Any help would be appreciated.

[Middle part of the "blink" effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDJYJ.png)

[Final part of the "blink" effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYxGQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

```kotlin
val EXTRA_FRAGMENT_ARG_KEY = ":settings:fragment_args_key"
val EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_ARGUMENTS = ":settings:show_fragment_args"

val args = bundleOf(
    EXTRA_FRAGMENT_ARG_KEY to "24 hour"
)
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS).apply {
    putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_ARGUMENTS, args)
}

startActivity(intent)
```

Titles in "Date & time" settings page and correspond preference keys:

- Use network-provided time - `auto_time`
- Date - `date`
- Time - `time`
- Use network-provided time zone - `auto_zone`
- Time zone - `timezone`
- Use locale default - `auto_24hour`
- Use 24-hour format - `24 hour`

Those preference keys followed AOSP([date_time_prefs.xml](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/date_time_prefs.xml;l=1?q=date_time_prefs.xml&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject)), however, OEMs can modify those preference keys on their devices(small possibility), it may be not working on some devices.

References:

- [Settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings)

Comment: Is this available for developer options too? I often need to reach the "Pointer location" there, for example.

Comment: sure, it works for developer options. but you have to ensure that the user has enabled developer options

Comment: you can try by changing `Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS` to `Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS' and `EXTRA_FRAGMENT_ARG_KEY` to `pointer_location`

Comment: Didn't work. Probably need to change the `to "24 hour"` part too. I also tried to change to `putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_ARGUMENTS, EXTRA_FRAGMENT_ARG_KEY)` .

Comment: just change the value of `EXTRA_FRAGMENT_ARG_KEY` to `"pointer_location"`

Comment: `EXTRA_FRAGMENT_ARG_KEY to "pointer_location"`

Comment: It works! Thank you! How did you find it? Do you know perhaps how to do it for SAW (system alert window) permission, so that it will scroll to the current app when you request it? Or for usage-data-access permission (or even get to the proper screen itself, to grant this permission to the app, instead of showing a list to grant it)  ?